# Why is list.remove faster than list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not fond of the following way of removing an element from a list:

```
try:
    lst.remove(elt)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

I know it is ok to use try except blocks in Python and I actually use them, but in this particular case I wish there was a `list.remove_if_exists(elt)` method when I don't really need to handle the case when the element is not in the list.

To make things clearer I tried using a list comprehension:

```
lst = [x for x in lst if x != elt]
```

However, this turned out to be slower:

```
In [3]: %timeit [x for x in lst if x != elt]
1000 loops, best of 3: 334 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit lst[:].remove(elt)
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.8 µs per loop
```

Why is that? And how can I remove an item from a list whether it exists or not in an elegant and efficient way?

**Edit:** people mentioned the reason is that `list.remove` stops when finding the element and the list comprehension goes through all elements, therefore, it should be slower.

So I tried removing the last element in the list, `elt = lst[-1]`, so that both processes reach the very end of the list:

```
In [7]: %timeit [x for x in lst if x != elt]
1000 loops, best of 3: 343 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit lst[:].remove(elt)
10000 loops, best of 3: 143 µs per loop
```

Why is `list.remove` still faster than the list comprehension? About twice as fast.

PS: I'd still love to suggestions for elegant and efficient ways of removing an element in a list without caring about its actual membership.

Comment: Hmmm, have You tried using `itertools.dropwhile(...)` ? maybe it could give You some intresting result to compare.

Comment: how about **if elt in lst**

Comment: `remove` only removes the first matching element. Your comprehension removes all matching elements. (This doesn't necessarily explain the performance, it's just a slight difference.)

Comment: @kofemann well I'm asking about why one is faster than the other; as of alternatives, yes, I am currently using that, but I think a one-liner would be cleaner.

Comment: @ajcr that's right. For my case, I am only concerned about one element.

Comment: Worth to note is also that Your list comprehension is equivalent to : built in `filter(function, iterable)`  :)

Comment: It really depends on position of element, try making a `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and remove `5`. `remove` is still bit faster but difference between slowest and fastest run is quite interesting.

Comment: @zipa you are right, if I define `elt = lst[-1]` the list comprehension takes 333 µs and `list.remove` takes 143 µs. These are closer results but still, this doesn't explain why `list.remove` is twice as fast.

Comment: @ajcr check out my latest edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your list comprehension is `O(n)` no matter what the content of the list, while `remove`  will iterate over the list until the first element is present and then will break. So this depends on the position of the element you want to remove.

A second reason that the `remove` is much faster is that it's implemented in C, the interpreter has overhead of calling the magic method `__eq__` while the C code calls a C function (`PyObject_RichCompareBool`).

You can see the source code here:

https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c

Search for `listremove`

Comment: I get that `list.remove` is *considerably* faster because it stops when finding the element, while the list comprehension iterates through the entire list. However, if you check out my edit, you can see that even when `list.remove` also reaches the end of the list it is still faster than the list comprehension. I take that the reason is precisely the second reason you pointed out? Or might it be something else?

Comment: It is indeed the second reason, @dabadaba.

Comment: That right, you can't compare python's interpreter with pure-C code. The C code doesn't have overhead like the interpreter has(objects, method lookups, list building etc).

Comment: The list comprehension has to create a new list. `list.remove` just modifies the existing list. That's much less work.